# Django Can't Read Membase Data?

Tags: python, membase

I have two Membase clients - a Django website and a small python test file. I observed that the data saved by the python file can't be seen by the Django website, it returns None. However, If I save the same data (same keys and values) in the Django website, the site will be able to read the keys/values then.

This is the same code I use in both clients:

```
import memcache
mc = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'])
ids = ["100000314125574", "100000335352069"]
users = mc.get_multi(ids)
```

I am using the python-memcache client library.

I have been trying to solve this for hours. Please share your ideas. It is a real mystery to me why Django can't read the data saved from another client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good troubleshooting step is just to telnet manually to 127.0.0.1 on port 11211 and do a 'get ' for that key.  If you get something back then at least you know the Membase server is functioning properly and you can focus on the Django side of things...where I'm much less knowledgeable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both clients are working, they can read/write data. It is just that Django can't read data written by other clients -- when I'm actually using the same code for writing/reading. I think too that this could be related to Django/the-python-client-library and not to Membase